# Classic ASP download PDF on page load

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I want to create a page that can display a message "Your download is about to begin" and then after a couple seconds open a "save as" dialogue which allows the visitor to download a file. Is this possible in Classic ASP VB Script? I know how to make a page stream a file, but it doesn't show the html of the page. The file I am offering is 20Mb so the script needs to handle large files sizes.

I currently have a meta redirect in place:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=/downloads/brochures/ACET_Products_and_Services_Directory_2013-14.pdf" />
```

But this isn't really any good.

I have asppdf installed on my server, and gave this a go:

```
<%
Set Pdf = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Pdf")
Set Doc = Pdf.OpenDocument("d:/websites/common/downloads/brochures/ACET_Products_and_Services_Directory_2013-14.pdf")
Doc.SaveHttp "attachment;filename=ACET_Products_and_Services_Directory_2013-14.pdf"
%>
```

This gets around the large file, but you can't stream the file and display HTML at the same time.

I have found plenty of ways to stream the file to the browser, but I can't it to do this after the page has been displayed.

This is another one I have tried:

```
<% 
    Response.Buffer = False 
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000 

    Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown" ' arbitrary 
    fn = "ACET_Products_and_Services_Directory_2013-14.pdf" 
    FPath = "d:\websites\common\downloads\brochures\" & fn 
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fn 

    Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
    chunk = 2048 
    adoStream.Open() 
    adoStream.Type = 1 
    adoStream.LoadFromFile(FPath) 

    iSz = adoStream.Size 

    Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", iSz 

    For i = 1 To iSz \ chunk 
        If Not Response.IsClientConnected Then Exit For 
        Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read(chunk) 
    Next 

    If iSz Mod chunk > 0 Then 
        If Response.IsClientConnected Then 
            Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read(iSz Mod chunk) 
        End If 
    End If 

    adoStream.Close 
    Set adoStream = Nothing 

    Response.End 
%>
```

With this I get a Error code: ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE from Chrome.

This is one that I have tried that almost works:

```
<% 
strFilePath = "d:/web sites/common/downloads/brochures/ACET_Products_and_Services_Directory_2013-14.pdf"

Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists(strFilePath) Then
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFilePath)
intFileSize = objFile.Size
Set objFile = Nothing

strFileName = "ACET_Products_and_Services_Directory_2013-14.pdf"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" & strFileName

Response.ContentType = "application/x-msdownload"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", intFileSize

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
objStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath
Do While Not objStream.EOS And Response.IsClientConnected
Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read(1024)
Response.Flush()
Loop
objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
Else
Response.write "Error finding file."
End if
Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
```

I then used <% response.redirect("download.asp") %> on the page I want it to download from, but as soon as I hit the page I get the file, but no page. Its this part I am struggling with.

SUCCESS!

```
<script> 
window.location.replace('download.asp'); 
</script>
```

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: What Lankymart is saying is that we won't write the code for you.  Show us what you've tried and we can give you pointers to what's wrong. There's also loads of stuff on the web on [how to delay](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-make-my-asp-page-pause-or-sleep.html) and [pushing files](https://blog.netnerds.net/2007/01/classic-asp-push-file-downloads-from-directory-outside-of-the-web-root/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little more trial and error I discovered creating a file called download.asp and putting this code in worked:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<% 
strFilePath = "d:/websites/common/downloads/brochures/ACET_Products_and_Services_Directory_2013-14.pdf"

Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists(strFilePath) Then
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFilePath)
intFileSize = objFile.Size
Set objFile = Nothing

strFileName = "ACET_Products_and_Services_Directory_2013-14.pdf"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" & strFileName

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", intFileSize

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
objStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath
Do While Not objStream.EOS And Response.IsClientConnected
Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read(1024)
Response.Flush()
Loop
objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
Else
Response.write "Error finding file."
End if
Set objFSO = Nothing
%>
```

I then placed this code on the page I wanted to display the instructions and then offer the automatic download:

```
<script> 
window.location.replace('download.asp'); 
</script>
```

I hope someone else finds this useful.

Steve